# Prevent perspective cameras from overlapping using multiple screens

Tags: unity, camera

I'm working on a shooting trainer project, where multiple cameras are placed beside each other to show a bigger range of environment. Each camera displays to a different screen. I find that the perspective cameras always show a part of each other, but I do not want those  cameras to show part of each other's view.

How do I align my perspective cameras to show a unique view?

Comment: For future, it helps to provide details pertinant to your question *in the actual question*. I am downvoting this question for lack of research, which becomes especially clear through your request for change in @StephaneHockenhull s answer, to accomodate minor changes you have made (but not specified, in your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you will need to put each cameras in the exact same 3D location, write a custom projection matrix to each cameras so they render off-center (and set them to render to different screens if that's what you intend to achieve).

In your camera script:

```
void LateUpdate() {
    Camera cam = Camera.main;
    Matrix4x4 m =  Matrix4x4.Perspective(cam.fieldOfView, cam.aspect * 3.0f, cam.nearClipPlane, cam.farClipPlane); 
    if(isLeftCamera){
        m[3, 0] = 2.0f;
    } else if(isRightCamera){
        m[3, 0] = -2.0f;
    } else { 
        // middle camera, don't shift
    }
    cam.projectionMatrix = m;
}
```

This makes the camera render 3 times as wide `cam.aspect * 3.0f` and offsets the rendering to render the left, right or middle part `m[3, 0] = ...`

Comment: @Gnemlock I'm guessing this is what is intended as using 2 cameras to render "wider" to the same screen would be pointless as you can simply change a single camera's aspect ratio if you want to stretch/squash a single screen.

Comment: thanks for your answer. seems its working. I have three caeras beside each other. I accept you answer if give me the answer for three. thank you.

Comment: im rendering to different screens. a camera for an screen

Comment: @virtouso your question mentions only 2 camera. if you want to do 3 you need to multiply the aspect ratio by 3.0f and then shift (m[3,0]) left by 2.0f, right by -2.0f and not shift the middle one.

Comment: This does appear to be the case of "user didn't provide the right details". Not a problem. This is a good answer :)